# PHP contact form validation

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I was just wondering if anybody could please help if this PHP code would work for validating HTML contact form inputs. I followed a tutorial to create this PHP validation, but i'm not sure if it will work. I don't have a webhost yet to test it out, but if anybody has a server,I will really be appreciated if anybody could do me a favour & try the code if you can send/receive email. Thank you!!
I'm using jQuery Validation Plugin for validating the form on client-side and this is the tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rdsz9Ie6h7I
 HTML form:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
<label for="yourname">Your Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="YourName"/>

<label for="youremail">Your Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="YourEmail" />

<label for="yourmessage">Your Message:</label>
<textarea  name="YourMessage"></textarea>

<fieldset>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send"/>
<input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset"/>
</fieldset>

PHP Code:

<?php

/* Subject and Email Variables */

 $emailSubject = 'Email from site visitor';
 $webMaster = 'YourEmail@mail.com';

/* Getting Form Data Variables */

    $nameField = $_POST['YourName'];
    $emailField = $_POST['YourEmail'];
    $messageField = $_POST['YourMessage'];

    $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Name: $YourName <br>
Email: $YourEmail <br>
Message: $YourMessage <br>

EOD;

    $headers = "From: $YourEmail\r\n";  
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

    $success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);

    $theResults = <<<EOD
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p style="font-size:12px;font-family:Tahoma,Verdana;">Thanks for your Message.</p>
</body>
</html>

EOD;

echo "$theResults";

?>
```

Comment: You don't need an off-site server to test your PHP out. Simply install [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#641).

Comment: Just an FYI if you have php 5.4 installed locally it comes with its own web server for testing http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: why don't you run on web server?

Comment: thank u for ur comment. Yah I've used xampp, but I get error
Notice: Undefined variable: YourName in C:\xampp\htdocs\site3\contact.php on line 17 for other inputs too. To be honest i'm not too familiar with PHP server side stuff, but i'll try to work around it.Thanks for the link i'll check it out.

Comment: That notice is because you're using the wrong variable name... note #2 in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a webserver right now you can install a local one and test it there. Completly free.

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#641

```
/* Getting Form Data Variables */

    $nameField = $_POST['YourName'];
    $emailField = $_POST['YourEmail'];
    $messageField = $_POST['YourMessage'];

    $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Name: $nameField<br>
Email: $emailField <br>
Message: $messageField <br>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur comment, i've tried, but I get these error

Notice: Undefined variable: YourName in C:\xampp\htdocs\site3\contact.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined variable: YourEmail in C:\xampp\htdocs\site3\contact.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined variable: YourMessage in C:\xampp\htdocs\site3\contact.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined variable: YourEmail in C:\xampp\htdocs\site3\contact.php on line 22
Thanks for your Message.

Comment: As the notices said you have not declared those variables correct. I edited my post. But there are still many other issues, also grammar onces.

Comment: Thank you alot Michael, didn't know about it, it works now. Not get those errors

Comment: I accept & appreciate all of ur answers/help, but plz let me try Stevens solution.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of issues

1. You're not validating at all on the PHP side.  I added validation and conditional rendering of success or failure messages below
2. You're not using the retrieved variable names (instead using $YourEmail) - the post names
3. Your form labels don't match the input names
4. Your form element isn't closed, and your fields aren't all in the fieldset, and the fieldset has no legend.
5. On case of failure, I added a value prefill in the form, so people don't get returned to a blank form when it falls to submit.
6. To do that, I put the form at the end, after the PHP

Code:

(Note: This would all be put into the file `contact.php`)

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    /* Getting Form Data Variables */

    $nameField = isset($_POST['YourName']) ? $_POST['YourName'] : null;
    $emailField = isset($_POST['YourEmail']) ? $_POST['YourEmail'] : null;
    $messageField = isset($_POST['YourMessage']) ? $_POST['YourMessage'] : null;

    // Validate
    $failures = array();
    if (strlen($nameField)) $failures[] = "Name is required";
    if (strlen($emailField)) $failures[] = "Email is required";
    if (filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) $failures[] = "Email is invalid";
    if (strlen($messageField)) $failures[] = "Message is required";

    // If validation errors, render them
    if (count($failures)) {
        echo "<p><b>Failed to submit: " . implode(", ", $failures) . "</b></p>";
    } else {
        /* Subject and Email Variables */
        $emailSubject = 'Email from site visitor';
        $webMaster = 'YourEmail@mail.com';

        $body = <<<EOD
            <br><hr><br>
            Name: {$nameField} <br>
            Email: {$emailField} <br>
            Message: {$messageField} <br>
        EOD;


        $headers = "From: {$emailField}\r\n";  
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
        $success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);

        $theResults = <<<EOD
            <p>Thanks for your Message.</p>
EOD;

        echo "$theResults";
    }
}

?>

<form action="contact.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact Us</legend>
        <label for="YourName">Your Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="YourName" value="<?=$nameField?>" />

        <label for="YourEmail">Your Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="YourEmail" value="<?=$emailField?>" />

        <label for="YourMessage">Your Message:</label>
        <textarea  name="YourMessage"><?=$messageField?></textarea>

        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send"/>
        <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Glad it works for you. :)  Please add upvote / checkmark so I get credit for that answer!  Thanks!

Comment: Hi thanks for pointing out, I forgot to include the closing form tag.
btw you've provided  $failures = array(); is that validation on client-side right? so i don't have to use jquery plugin to validate the form?

Comment: No, you don't need jQuery anymore.